# Hello, I am making put request using axios and vue.js to ASP.NET Core controller at backend but it is passing null

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am making put request for updating product in vue.js but it is passing null to my controller action method.

The vue.js code for updating product is:

```
updateProduct() {
     this.loading = true;
     axios.put('/Admin/products', this.productModel)
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res.data);
             this.products.splice(this.objectIndex, 1, res.data);
         })
         .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
         .then(() => {
             this.loading = false;
         });
 }
```

My `index.cshtml` file is:

```
@page
@model Shop.Ui.Pages.Admin.IndexModel
@{
}
@section scripts
    {
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/admin/main.js"></script>

}
<div id="app">
 <button v-on:click="getProducts">Get Products</button>
    <div>
        <p v-for="(product,index) in products">
            {{product.id}} - {{product.name}} - {{product.description}}
            <a @@click="editProduct(product,index)">Edit</a>
            <a @@click="deleteProduct(product.id)">Remove</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        
        <input v-model="productModel.name"/> 
        <input v-model="productModel.description" />
        <input v-model.number="productModel.value" />
        <button @@click="createProduct" v-if="!productModel.id">Create Product</button>
        <button @@click="updateProduct" v-else>Update Product</button>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

I am making put request to this action method but the request object is null

````
[HttpPut("products")]
```c#
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromBody] UpdateProduct.Request request)
    => Ok(await new UpdateProduct(_ctx).Do(request));
````

Here is my code for UpdateProduct.cs and request class.
public class UpdateProduct
{
private ApplicationDbContext _context;

```
public UpdateProduct(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}


public async Task<Response> Do(Request request)
{
    try
    {
        var product = _context.Products.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        product.Name = request.Name;
        product.Description = request.Description;
        product.Value = request.Value;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return new Response
        {
            Id = product.Id,
            Name = product.Name,
            Description = product.Description,
            Value = product.Value
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception here, you can log it or throw a custom exception.
        // For example, you can log the exception and then throw a custom exception.
        // Logging should be done using a proper logging library like Serilog or NLog.

        // Log the exception
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");

        // You can re-throw a custom exception if needed.
        throw new ApplicationException("An error occurred while updating the product.");
    }
}



[Serializable]
public class Request
{
    public int Id {  get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

}
```

}

```
Please can anyone help me?
```

Comment: Hi @prajwal lama, how is your model design and could you pls share the data you put to the request?

Comment: @Rena thanks for responding I have added data that I put in request in my question again please can you have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your `UpdateProduct.Request` definition, but I encountered similar before. It's at CS API side, make sure your `request` model class match exactly as what you posting, give default values if some fields are optional. Pay attention to null and non-null declaration in CS.

For example:

```
public class product
{
  [Required]
  public string name {get; set;} // this is required, non-null
  public string name {get; set;} = ""; // this is optional
  ...
}
```

Comment: i have done it but i am getting same errors

Comment: Have you tried console.log at client to see what exactly posting to API?

Comment: No,but data is in payload but it still passes null to controller